# yii2 gridview hide empty column not working

Tags: gridview, yii2

I want to hide yii2 gridview empty column if value is null but my code is not working.

I have tried this code:

```
[
 'attribute'=>'division',
 'value'=>'divisionName.name',
 'visible' => function ($data) {
  if ('divisionName.name' == NULL) {
   return '0'; // or return true;
  } else {
   return '1'; // or return false;
  }
 },
]
```

And then tried this:

```
[
 'attribute'=>'division',
 'value'=>'divisionName.name',
 'visible' => function ($data) {
  if ('divisionName.name' == NULL) {
   return  true;
  } else {
   return  false;
  }
 },
]
```

Above both line of codes not working.

If divisionName.name equal to null then hide entire column from gridview, what is wrong with this code?

Comment: This is totally confused, IMO. You cannot set a function for `'visible'`, only true or false is allowed. And this property is only evaluated once,  it does not check for each row if there is a value or not and decides whether the column should be shown or not. And `'divisionName.name' == NULL` is false - you compare a string with NULL. And `if(...) return true; else return false;` ... don't you know that this is absolutely superfluous?

Comment: @robsch in   'visible' attrinute you can assingn alos the result of a test ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have also a logical problem because you would show a null value and hide a not null value  ..

The right solution is based on an check for the hide/show condition before the widget is showed

```
$showDivision = myFunctioForShow(...);

[
     'attribute'=>'division',
      .....
      'visible' => $showDivision ,
] ,
```

Comment: Thanks I will try.

Comment: `'division' == null` is always false.

Comment: @robsch  why 'division'   == NULL is always false?

Comment: Don't you compare a string with NULL?

Comment: @robsch   in this case 'division'  si  not a string but a key  taht the gridview widget should convert the related column value to the proper value  .. 'division'  is not a literal string but the key for column gridview  ..

Comment: I get what you mean. But I would be surprised if Yii does this. You just pass a normal array to Gridview.

Comment: I have used visible with test .. in several situation  .. and the 'column_name'  index key is used for retrive the value ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117091/discussion-between-robsch-and-scaisedge).

Comment: @robsch you are right, why we compare string with NULL? The right way is: `(empty(division)) ? false: true` but this one also not working.